# How do I mark incoming iptables request from unknown MAC address with mark 99 using conntrack

Tags: iptables, conntrack

I have my iptables rules running for years without incident but after allowing all trusted MAC's access by:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source $MAC -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -m mac --mac-source $MAC -j ACCEPT
```

I am trying to mark other mac addresses like:

```
/sbin/iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i $INT_DEV -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 99
```

but when I try to read that address now by doing
`conntrack -L | grep "src=10.1.1.234"`
I don't see my unknown 10.1.1.234 freeloader anywhere...
Yet I want to continue in iptables to divert my freeloader to a login page by means of

````
/sbin/iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -m mark --mark 99 -j DROP```  
And obviously it doesn't work because I can't even see it from my conntrack listing.  
What am I doing wrong here..?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a difference between a *packet* mark, aka just *mark*, *firewall mark* or *fwmark*, and a conntrack entry mark, aka *ctmark*, *connection mark* or *connmark*: the former is attached to the packet's [skbuff](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/linux/skbuff.h?h=v6.6#n817), the later is attached to the [conntrack entry](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack.h?h=v6.6#n113). There are distinct *iptables* [mat](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#mark)-[ches](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#connmark) and [tar](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#MARK)-[gets](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#CONNMARK) for both, including ways to [pass the mark from the packet to the connection entry](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#save) or [from the connection entry to the packet](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#restore%7E2).

Here there's no need to use this mark with *conntrack* for this case and `conntrack -L` is simply not the right tool to display a dropped packet (see last paragraph). When using the `iptables-nft` variant the easiest way to see marked packets for debugging purposes (else just using `-j LOG` would add the packet's mark in its logs) is to trace them and use `xtables-monitor --trace` to display their fate (`iptables-legacy` would send this to kernel logs, and might easily flood logs, beside it doesn't play well with network namespaces: that's a rare non-compatible change between the -legacy and the -nft variant).

So one possible example:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i $INT_DEV -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 99
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -m mark --mark 99 -j TRACE
```

[...]

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m mark --mark 99 -j DROP
```

The detailed fate of all such marked packets between `-j TRACE` and `-j DROP` (or `-j ACCEPT` plus all further processing for these elected few) can now be followed, very verbosely, with:

```
xtables-monitor --trace
```

To limit the verbosity, one could trace only packets starting a new flow by changing the `TRACE` rule like this:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -m mark --mark 99 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j TRACE
```

In addition: the first packet of such flow does trigger the creation of a *conntrack* entry that (even without mark) would normally be visible in event mode using `conntrack -E -p tcp --dport 80`. But when this packet is dropped, the tentative conntrack entry is never [confirmed](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_proto.c?h=v6.6#n249) and the event will never be made available to `conntrack`. While it will be invisible with the `conntrack` command, it would still be visible within rules using `-m conntrack --ctproto tcp --ctorigdstport 80` before it's dropped. Any further retry will again be a first packet which will create a tentative entry, which won't be confirmed because the packet was dropped etc.

So `conntrack` can only be used to display flows that got their first packet not dropped, else there's no flow made available to it.